# how to get rid of duplicated content

Tags: reactjs

All classes within our ReactJs project are designed by extending the Component class.

```
class X extends Component{
...
 getType = (type) => {
   ...
 }
}

class Y extends Compnent{
....
  getType = (type) => {
  --
 }
}
```

Recently some classes needed the getType method, which has been added in the particular classes. 
By now or code sniffer is refusing this code due to code duplication.

I know, I could easily create an own class with this method inside, but that implements that all classes must be extended from this one.

The question which I would like to ask is:

What is the best approach to solve this without adapting each classes too much.

Comment: If they're both extending from `Component`, you could just add to the `Component` prototype and then override it. Also, are you saying that `getType()` is the exact same for each? Does it rely on `this`? If not, then couldn't you just extract it to outside the class?

Comment: @Colin,thank you for your answer... could you plase give me some example or point me to the right direction...  the getType is exact the same for each, and is not using the this reference

Comment: What is `getType` supposed to do? What is `type`?

Comment: is just used to return some div element depending on the passed argument. The argument depends on the class which is currently used.   let type = this.getType(someDataForType);

Comment: How does the argument depend on the class, where is it coming from? Can you add all the relevant code?

Comment: Each class uses an API call. Then in der render() method we collect the response values.

Comment: It is best to use HOC for this https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: Not really sure what you're actually trying to do, so I can't help — sorry.

Comment: @UjinT34, that's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.